# What is the "permanence relation" really?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, induced-representations, notation

I have come across the words "permanence relation" in a 1969 paper by Keith Hannabuss [*The Dirac equation in de Sitter space*](https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/2/3/005).  The only other similar google hit for this phrase appears in another paper of Hannabuss's with Alan Carey: [*Infinite dimensional groups and Riemann surface field theories*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02099552).

As far as I can make out, this is the following.  Suppose that $G$ is a group and $H<G$ a subgroup.  (I'm being purposefully vague here about the kinds of groups: finite, Lie,...)

Let $\operatorname{Res}: \operatorname{Rep}(G) \to \operatorname{Rep}(H)$ denote the restriction functor from the category of complex $G$-modules to the category of complex $H$-modules, and let $\operatorname{Ind}: \operatorname{Rep}(H) \to \operatorname{Rep}(G)$ denote the induction functor going the other way.

Then the "permanence relation" seems to say that for every $G$-module $V$ and every $H$-module $W$,

$$\operatorname{Ind}(W) \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} V \cong \operatorname{Ind}(W \otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\operatorname{Res}(V))$$
as $G$-modules.

This strikes me as the $\otimes$-version of the following isomorphism

$$\operatorname{Hom}_H(W,\operatorname{Res}(V)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_G(\operatorname{Ind}(W),V)$$

showing that $\operatorname{Ind}$ and $\operatorname{Res}$ are adjoint functors.

I'm not asking for a proof of the "permanence relation", which at least for finite group is not difficult, but more for a modern interpretation along the lines of the categorical interpretation of the above isomorphism of $\operatorname{Hom}$'s.  And perhaps also for a more modern name by which it might be known?

Thanks in advance.

**Added**

I just came across another name for this formula (based Tom's comment below): apparently it's also called a "push-pull" formula and there's even an [earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18799/ubiquity-of-the-push-pull-formula) about it!  Although that question explicitly mentions the above "permanence relation" as one of the avatars of the "push-pull" formula, none of the answers address this particular avatar.  Still, if people think that this question is a duplicate, I will not be offended if it is closed as such!

Comment: Arunas Liulevicius, in his "Arrows, Symmetries and Representation Rings", interprets $H$-modules as $G$-vector bundles over the discrete $G$-manifold (i. e., $G$-set) $G\diagup H$. Restriction is pullback and induction is pushforward (defined for a finite covering). This way, I guess, the permanence relation becomes the projection formula for vector bundles - which, however, is not less mysterious to me...

Comment: More precisely, a $G$-vector bundle over a discrete $G$-manifold $M$ (this simply means a $G$-set with $G$ acting from the left) means a family $\left(V_m\right)_{m\in M}$ of vector spaces $V_m$ of $G$ for each $m\in M$ equipped with maps $t_{m,g}:V_m\to V_{gm}$ for each $m\in M$ and $g\in G$ satisfying $t_{gm,h}t_{m,g}=t_{m,hg}$ for any $m\in M$, $g\in G$ and $h\in H$. Of course, when $M$ is the trivial $1$-point $G$-set, then there is only one $V_m$ and thus a $G$-vector bundle is just a representation of $G$. Generally, when $M$ is the $G$-set $G\diagup H$, ...

Comment: ... then the $G$-vector bundle is uniquely determined (up to isomorphism) by the vector space $V_1$ and the maps $t_{h,1}$ for $h\in H$, so it is more or less the same as a representation of $H$.

Comment: The equation expressing what might be called the "naturality of the cap product" (pulling back the cohomology class $a$, capping it with the homology class $b$, pushing it forward gives the same result as pushing $b$ forward and capping with $a$) seems to have the old-fashioned name "the permanence formula". At least, that is what Bott called it when I was learning algebraic topology from him in the 1970s. 

Comment: Thanks, Tom.  This explains a couple of the google hits I found.  One of them, in fact, to a paper by Bott and Cattaneo.

Comment: Thanks, Darij.  I have tried to get Liulevicius's paper online without success.  It seems that we don't subscribe.  I'll try the paper version in the library tomorrow.  I am familiar with the theory of induced representations both for finite and Lie groups and its geometric description in terms of homogeneous vector bundles, but I'm clearly missing the "big picture".

Comment: José: http://rapidshare.com/files/410362606/liulevicius.pdf for Liulevicius' paper. However, it is far from being easy to read...

Comment: Darij: Indeed... but thanks very much for making it available.

Comment: The link to a copy of Liulevicius's paper at `rapidshare.com` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/78044) above is now broken. For those who have access, the article can also be found at [doi:10.1016/0022-4049(80)90103-6](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(80)90103-6) ([Zbl 0448.55013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0448.55013)).